# EasyMock says unexpected invocation when the invocation is expected

Tags: java, easymock

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with EasyMock. I've set up some expectations, but when I run my tests, EasyMock fails because my expectations execute as specified. Here is an example of the failure:

```
Unexpected method call MyClass.myMethod(en, EasyMock for interface com.google.common.collect.Multimap, EasyMock for interface java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue, EasyMock for interface java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue):
  MyClass.myMethod(en, EasyMock for interface com.google.common.collect.Multimap, EasyMock for interface java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue, EasyMock for interface java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue): expected: 100, actual: 0
```

The test looks like this:

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = createMock(Multimap.class);
BlockingQueue<MyType> myTypeQueue = createMock(BlockingQueue.class);
BlockingQueue<MyOtherType> myOtherTypeQueue = createMock(BlockingQueue.class);
MyClass myClass = createMock(MyClass.class);

QueueFactory queueFactory = createMock(QueueFactory.class);
expect(queueFactory.<MyType>getQueue(100)).andReturn(myTypeQueue).times(2);
expect(queueFactory.<MyOtherType>getQueue(100)).andReturn(myOtherTypeQueue).times(2);

expect(myClass.myMethod("en", multimap, myTypeQueue, myOtherTypeQueue)).andReturn(something).times(100);
replayAll();

// The actual method to test
TestClass myTestInstance = new TestClass(myClass);
myTestInstance.testMethod(queueFactory, multimap);
myTestInstance.testMethod(queueFactory, multimap);
```

Here is the method I am testing:

```
public class MyTestClass
    private MyClass myClass;

    public MyTestClass(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    public void testMethod(QueueFactory queueFactory, Multimap<String, String> multimap) {
        BlockingQueue<MyType> myTypeQueue = queueFactory.getQueue(100);
        BlockingQueue<MyOtherType> myOtherTypeQueue = queueFactory.getQueue(100);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
            myClass.myMethod("en", multimap, myTypeQueue, myOtherTypeQueue);
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I've tried replacing the mocks with instances of HashMultimap and ArrayBlockingQueue. I've also tried wrapping all of the method parameter's in `EasyMock.eq`. Neither of these approaches solved the issue.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Where are you invoking the method?

Comment: The invocation of `MyClass.myMethod` happens inside the method I am testing. The method I am testing is invoked after the `replayAll()`

Comment: Let's see it and post the full stack trace.

Comment: That is the full stack trace. I've updated the test to show some more stuff.

Comment: Your test is reporting that `myClass.myMethod` is not being invoked. So show us that it is.

Comment: I'm basically asking for a MCVE, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: No, the test is reporting that myClass.myMethod is being invoked with unexpected parameters.

Comment: Why do you say that? I see `expected: 100, actual: 0`.

Comment: `Unexpected method call MyClass.myMethod` I've updated the question with an MCVE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67625/discussion-between-max-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of type erasure, there's nothing EasyMock can do to determine that

```
expect(queueFactory.<MyType>getQueue(100))
```

is different from

```
expect(queueFactory.<MyOtherType>getQueue(100))
```

Each `expect` call registers an expectation for a number of invocations, in order. So

```
expect(queueFactory.<MyType> getQueue(100)).andReturn(myTypeQueue).times(2);
```

states that the first two times you invoke `getQueue(100)`, it will return `myTypeQueue`. If you follow that with

```
expect(queueFactory.<MyOtherType> getQueue(100)).andReturn(myOtherTypeQueue).times(1);
```

The next two calls to `getQueue(100)` will return `myOtherTypeQueue`.

In your `testMethod`, you invoke

```
BlockingQueue<MyType> myTypeQueue = queueFactory.getQueue(100);
BlockingQueue<MyOtherType> myOtherTypeQueue = queueFactory.getQueue(100);
```

which is invoking `getQueue(100)` twice, ie. the first two times. These will both return `myTypeQueue`, which breaks the expectation on `myClass.myMethod`.

It works when you only do it once, because the first `expect` returns `myTypeQueue` and the second returns `myOtherTypeQueue` which then matches your `myClass.myMethod` expectations.

You can fix it by registering each in order, once

```
expect(queueFactory.<MyType> getQueue(100)).andReturn(myTypeQueue).times(1);
expect(queueFactory.<MyOtherType> getQueue(100)).andReturn(myOtherTypeQueue).times(1);
expect(queueFactory.<MyType> getQueue(100)).andReturn(myTypeQueue).times(1);
expect(queueFactory.<MyOtherType> getQueue(100)).andReturn(myOtherTypeQueue).times(1);
```